# SQLite Xamarin/C# inserting data

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am developing an application. I have connected my project to SQLIte, now I am trying to add an advert, which I am failing to do.

```
my SQLInterface 

public interface ISQLiteInterface
    {

        SQLiteConnection GetSQLiteConnection();

    }
```

my Droid SQL

```
public class SQLiteDb : ISQLiteInterface
    {
        public SQLiteDb()
        {

        }
        public SQLiteConnection GetSQLiteConnection()
        {
            var fileName = "Mydatabase.db";
            var dbpath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            var path = Path.Combine(dbpath, fileName);
            var connection = new SQLiteConnection(path);


            return connection;
        }

    }
}

my model

 public class AdLogEntry
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string SellerName { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Picture> Pictures { get; set; }
        public List<Video> Videos { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
        public string Video { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Price { get; set; }
        public string  LoadedDate { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }

    public class Picture
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public byte[] Image { get; set; }
    }
    public class Video
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public byte[] ImageVideo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

this is my task

```
private async void NextStep_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           await SaveAdLog();
        }

        private async Task SaveAdLog()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(NameEntry.Text) || (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(PriceEntry.Text) || (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(LocationEntry.Text))))
            {
                await DisplayAlert("error", "fill all entries", "OK");
            }
            else {
                var adLogEntry = new AdLogEntry
                {
                    Location = LocationEntry.Text,
                    Price = PriceEntry.Text,
                    Name = NameEntry.Text,

                };
                var result =  _adService.CreateAddLogEntry(adLogEntry); //ok
                if (result == null)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Gratulace", "", "OK");
                    App.Current.MainPage = new AppShell();
                }

            };

        }
```

this is my advertservice

```
  class AdService
    {
        private SQLiteConnection _conn;

        public AdService()
        {
            _conn = DependencyService.Get<Helpers.ISQLiteInterface>().GetSQLiteConnection();
            _conn.CreateTable<AdLogEntry>();

        }


        public string CreateAddLogEntry(AdLogEntry adLogEntry)
        {
            var detail =  _conn.Table<AdLogEntry>();
           var d1 = detail.Connection.Insert(adLogEntry);
           return "Thank you";
        }

    }

}
```

Once I press the button nothing happens. When I try to debug it i get 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Edit.
This app is supposed to be something like LetItGo so all values should be able to repeat 
I have ISQLite interface implemented.

Comment: Will a combination of `Location`, `Price` and `Name` values be unique? If yes, you can use it in `Where` clause.

Comment: No, it cant be. Its supposed be like online second hand..something like LetITGo

Comment: Ok, which fields combination will be unique? As for me, it can be `SellerName`, `Price`, `Name` and `LoadedDate` (maybe, field `Quality` will be needed in the database to allow someone to sell several identical items). Anyway you should find such combination you can use as hashcode of the advert.

Comment: Well the seller should be able to sell more than one item. The thing i am not able to come up with any other method coudl solve this.

Comment: So `var d1 = detail.Where(i => i.SellerName == adLogEntry.SellerName && i.Name == adLogEntry.Name && <any conditions to identify the advert>).FirstOrDefault();` should give you desired result.

Comment: This will surely work for the other thing i want to do. Thank you. I found a way to deal with my issuer, but it still doesnt work//I made an edit

Comment: which specific line causes the null ref exception?

Comment: in my Task var result =  _adService.CreateAddLogEntry(adLogEntry);

Comment: So basically my  public string CreateAddLogEntry(AdLogEntry adLogEntry)
        {

            var detail =  _conn.Table<AdLogEntry>();
           var d1 = detail.Connection.Insert(adLogEntry);
           return "Thank you";}

Comment: @Kon You have set instance for _adService, like `_adService = new AdService();`somehere?

Comment: that was the issue, took me all day.. thank you though

Comment: @kon I have updated my reply, can you help to mark my reply as answer to close your thread? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your error message, I can not see where you instantiate a new instance of the AdService class.

So please try to add the following code before you call _adService.CreateAddLogEntry() method.

```
_adService = new AdService();
```

Answer (score 0):

i think SQLite can't process this properties in your model

**List< Picture >**  and
 **List< Video >** 

`public List<Picture> Pictures { get; set; }
public List<Video> Videos { get; set; }`

I suggest that you change the property to `string` and serialize the data before saving